What will happen when option premium rise very high for shorting put?
Suppose the commission is zero for trading stock option such as trading stock in some broker ,and all other fee is zero.There is a put option,exercise price is 2.5 USD, option premium is 2 USD,i have only 10000 USD cash in my account.let's have a discussion on the classic short cash-secured put strategy.
1.Can i  short put 200 contracts?
10000/(2.5-2)/100 = 20000/100 =200 contracts
2.If the option premium rise to 5 USD,what will happen?
For a put option ,it is nonsense that option premium is larger than its exercise price.But if the trader have large amount money ,they can buy it at any price.
On April 21, 2020, the price of May WTI crude oil futures on the NYMEX fell to -$37.63 per barrel.
It is possible that the option premium rise to 5 USD.
So when the option premium rise to 5 USD in this case,my account will be forced liquidation and all cash lost?
The earning in my account maybe is 200*(2-5)*100 = -60000?
Or i can just do nothing ,waiting someone to exercise the put option?

If you short a put, you are selling puts, not buying them. Are you talking about buying puts to have a short position on the stock?

No ,it is cash secured short put,no short stock position at all,just cash and open to sell put option.


1.Can i short put 200 contracts?

Well, shorting a put means selling it, so you don't pay anything up front - so whether you can short 200 contracts depends on the margin requirements of your broker or the exchange.

For a put option, it is nonsense that option premium is larger than its exercise price.  But if the trader have large amount money, they can buy it at any price.

Sure, but why would they pay $5 for the option to sell their stock for $2.50? At worst their stock will be worthless and there's no need to sell it.

On April 21, 2020, the price of May WTI crude oil futures on the NYMEX fell to -$37.63 per barrel.

That is a different situation - those were physically-settled futures contracts that required someone to actually deliver or store the oil that was purchased. (look up other questions on this site to see why they actually went negative)  With stocks, there is no storage or carry costs, so there's no plausible scenario in which one would have to pay to store or transport them.

It is possible that the option premium rise to 5 USD.

No it's not. The premium of a put will not go above the strike price.

You're right, it is nonsense for a short put to have premium in excess of its strike, anyone paying more is throwing money away. This is because the floor is $0. The shares can't go negative. There are cases where people  pay a little over intrinsic value to exit a short put in order to avoid assignment, but you won't find people paying $5 for a put with $2.5 strike (2.5p).
Your math is correct, you would need $50 of capital per short put if there were no fees at all for opening/closing/taking assignment and cash-secured. Though very unlikely, if the price of the 2.5p went to $5, you wouldn't be able to buy them back to close, you'd have to hold until expiration/assignment.
Some futures contracts require physical delivery of the commodity, and those can go negative because of the logistics/costs involved with physical delivery. In your example, there was a supply glut already, then oil demand dried up. Storage facilities filled quickly, and some people who had no place to put more oil (or traders who never intended to take delivery of many barrels of oil) had to pay someone else to take the oil for them.

The market maker is obligated to make a market so contracts can be bought to close.  You might not like the price but they'll be available.

@BobBaerker Right, my point was that OP wouldn't be able to close if the option price was higher since they have no extra capital after using it all to secure the contracts.

I'm confused.  In one sentence you said that it is nonsense for a short put to have premium in excess of its strike and later you said that if the price of the 2.5p went to $5, you wouldn't be able to buy them back to close.  If the latter could occur, that would be a beautiful arb.

@BobBaerker It's nonsense for people to spend $5 on a 2.5p it shouldn't happen. However, if it did happen after OP had exhausted their buying power by selling cash-secured 2.5p's for $2 then they would be unable to close their short puts due to lack of buying power, they can only buy back their short puts when it's for a debit less than the credit they received, or they can wait until expiration/assignment. The point of entertaining the theoretical is just that it wouldn't hurt OP, their risk is capped.

You are not going to be able to sell 200 puts because your margin calculation is incorrect. The CBOE minimum margin for naked puts is the greater of:

20% of the underlying price minus the out-of-money amount plus the option premium


10% of the strike price plus the option premium

Brokers may require more.  For example, Tastytrade requires a minimum margin of $250 per contract.
You have overlooked early assignment.  You've maxed out your cash. What happens if you are assigned on your short puts and you don't have the cash to cover?  Violation?

Assignment does not create a margin problem on cash-secured puts. The provided example of 2.5p for 2/share premium takes $50/contract to secure with cash.
